# WCF (like) Services in linux

Tags: services, mono, hosting-services

I have been working on migrating machines at my workplace from windows to linux, and one stumbling block is our usage of C# wcf services. We like to host various c# services on one machine for multiple desktop machines to call.

I understand that services are a different concept in linux, but is there an equivalent or a competing technology under linux I should consider?

I am also aware of the `mono` project and I know it can do this to some limited ability. I have just heard mixed reviews (perhaps I'm wrong?), Are there other tools I should look at that C++ might be able to capitalize on?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use tools below

**option 1** : ServiceStack

***doc:***

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342871.aspx

**option 2** : node.js (best Case)

hosting very easy (with multi line)

***doc:***

- http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/